# find/grep outputs two lines for each file it finds match

Tags: find, grep

I search my code base to find string patterns and list all the files where the pattern is found but only the file and not the lines on which it is found:

```
find . -name *.java -exec grep -l 'someText' {} \; -print 2>/dev/null
```

However, it outputs two lines for each file found.  Why does that happen and how should I modify the command to list unique file names?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

grep prints files names  AND returns a True/False value; if the value is True, then the `-print` action prints the file. So you have two possibilities:

```
find . -name '*.java' -exec grep -l 'someText' {} \;  2>/dev/null
```

or

```
find . -name '*.java' -exec grep -q 'someText' {} \; -print 2>/dev/null
```

And remember to quote `*.java`. Otherwise the shell may expand it to the list of java files in the current directory.

Also note you don't have to run one `grep` per file, you'd better do:

```
find . -name '*.java' -exec grep -l 'someText' {} +  2>/dev/null
```

Note the `2>/dev/null` suppresses the errors of both `find` and `grep`. If you only want to make `grep` quiet, you can write it instead:

```
find . -name '*.java' -exec grep -sl 'someText' {} +
```

And last, note that the GNU implementation of `grep` can also do `find`'s job:

```
grep -slr --include='*.java' 'someText' .
```

Comment: Thanks Stephane for your edit; your contribution in this answer is now more important and better than mine! It could not be more comprehensive.